# Cannot debug MVC project due to IIS change(8=>7.5) on VS2012 RC

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I have installed web matrix and It has somehow removed the existing IIS Express 8.0, that is installed by default during the VS2012RC installation. I think that is because the web Matrix is using IIS 7.5. So that it has replaced the IIS Express 8 with IIS Express 7.5.

So my tech lead told me to remove the existing IIS 7.5 that has been installed during the installation of Web Matrix, And I removed it. So I have no IIS for debugging. So once I tried to install the IIS 8 manually and it says that there is a existing version of IIS Express 8. So that I can not even install the IIS Express 8.

So I did a repair to my VS2012RC. After a lengthy process it finally gave me a report as

```
"IIS 8.0 Express
Package failed"
```

So, Now I am totally stuck with this. Can some one good at this VS stuff help me on this issue.

Another thing is, previously when I open the project and it was not loaded(It says the project is not loaded) So, then when I write click on it and do a reload it said "`For debugging you have to have IIS 8.0 and ask me to download it and install` ".

When I click next and then it goes to "MS web platform Installer" and direct me to the "IIS 7.5 download page" But the install button was enabled and says its installed. What should I do to overcome this issue. This is like a nightmare.

I also Tried to use "Fix it" and Its beta testing is over and I can not do a proper uninstall of the IIS 8, which says that is still existing.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't tell from your question, did you try the IIS 8 Express RC download from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29937?

Comment: Yes I downloaded x64 version and when tried to install it says to there is a existing version and you have to download it before installing. but in program list there is no IIS 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I did was using MS web platform Installer my option of IIS Express 7.5 and IIS Express 8.0 was gone due to a registry issue. But there was another IIS 8.0 which is compatible with Windows XP and Vista and upper. So I downloaded it installed. It installed in no time and then I opened the project and changed my solution configuration, single start up to my website project. And it worked. That saved me form the havoc that day.

Later I uninstalled the IIS 8.0(Xp compatible) and then did a repair again to my VS 2012 and it installed correctly that time. Then I changed the configuration as said above and done.

If you have the same kind of problem you have to check the configuration also. Since I forgot that this took even longer instead of repairing time for the VS 2012 as well as the system restore.